# How do I convert a string into a string array String()?

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net

My routine expects a string array:

```
Private Sub AddToQueue(asFiles() As String)
    ...
End Sub
```

I want to be able to let a property accept both a String as well as a String() array. However, because properties can not be overloaded, I wrote two individual singular/plural properties. While the plural variant is unproblematic:

```
Public Property AddFiles As String()
    ...
    Set(asValue As String())
        AddToQueue(asValue)
    End Set
End Property
```

However, the single string variant needs to be converted into a string array.

```
Public Property AddFile As String
    ...
    Set(sValue As String)
        AddToQueue(...)              'How to convert sValue to String()?
    End Set
End Property
```

I can not find any conversion function allowing me to do so, the general error is

> Value of type 'String' can not be converted to 'String()'.

Surely there must be a way to pass this single String to my routine?

Comment: `AddToQueue(New String() {sValue})`?

Comment: `AddToQueue({sValue})`?

Comment: @VisualVincent : All so new... Sorry for being trivial. Is removing the question good practice?

Comment: Not sure. Do what you think feels best. If you don't remove it I'll write an answer instead. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an [**array initializer**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13tek7e(v=vs.100).aspx) and pass the result to the method:

```
AddToQueue(New String() {sValue})
```

The above can also be written like:

```
AddToQueue({sValue})
```

but I prefer to be explicit. :)